# I can't create HTTP/HTTPS server on Linux VPS

Tags: node.js, linux, http, server, vps

I have set up a simple HTTP server with NodeJS that is working in Local Mode, but when I'm executing it on a Debian server, I can't access it, this is my simple code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
console.log("ok1");
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf-8', function (error, content) {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            "Content-Type": "text/html"
        });
        res.end(content);
    });
});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Un client est connecté !');
});
server.listen(8080);
```

And I get this error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9vUE.png)

Thank you very much !

Comment: its possible that firewall is enabled and blocking connections to 8080 port.
Also its possible that you start server in terminal, than close SSH connection, and server is stopped, - you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever to make server running even if you terminate ssh connection

Answer (score 0):

The server seems fine. It probably isn't the problem. Try pinging the server from your machine and pinging your machine from the server. If it only goes one way then the issue must be firewall. If it doesn't go both ways make sure they are actually on the same network.

Comment: Also can you acces the localhost:8080 from the server or does it fail too?

Comment: Thank you very much, I maybe found the issue:
When I start my app, I can execute 'telnet localhost 8080' from the VPS server, but when I try with the IP from my machine, I got an error. But I still don't know how to resolve it :/